Install In-House UWP via Intune
My ultimate goal is to have an UWP application be installed over Intune on a company's network. We previously were using the Microsoft Store LOB to distribute the application. We are now trying to transition into using Intune, but the app will not install successfully. The goal is to avoid doing Sideloading by the way.
I have an APPX that is code signed with a certificate given by the company. Intune will accept the APPX when configuring the app for setup. When the app is attempted to be installed on another machine, an error happens. It says a few things like -

AppX Deployment operation failed for package <package name> with error 0x80073CFF.


Deployment of package <package name> with package origin Unknown failed because no valid license or sideloading policy could be applied.

I am struggling to figure out what needs to change to make this work. Do I need to package the application differently? Do I need to create an installer (MSIX) and try to install it through Intune that way?
Just for some background - I know of 3 different ways within Visual Studio to generate the APPX:

Build in Release mode & bin folder has APPX
Right Click Project -> Publish -> Create App Packages (Mirosoft Store -or- Sideloading)

Not sure if I need to use one of these specifically to get it to be happy or not.
